# Grafana duplicates labels based on all possible labels permutations

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, grafana

I have **Prometheus** + **Grafana** setup. **Prometheus** collects `Counter` and gives it two labels:

- Message_Type - from 1 to 27
- Provider - one from `['A', 'B', 'C', ... , 'I']` (length is 9)

I imported it into **Grafana** and applied **Labels to fields** transformation on `Message_Type` and **expected to see 27 lines**.

What I actually see is 27*9 = 243 entries!
I think Grafana created all possible permutations:

```
+-----+--------------+----------+
| NUM | Message_Type | Provider |
+-----+--------------+----------+
| 1   | 1            | A        |
| 2   | 1            | B        |
| 3   | 1            | C        |
| ... | ...          | ...      |
| 9   | 1            | I        |
| 10  | 2            | A        |
| ... | ...          | ...      |
| 243 | 9            | I        |
+-----+--------------+----------+
```

This is how it looks in **Grafana**:
[image]

How to merge these labels so that there are no duplicates?

Comment: if you found a solution please post it here so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you added your Prometheus query to your question. In order to group metrics by the same field `Message_Type` in the legend you can do something like the following:

```
count(<your_query>) by (Message_Type)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Didn't realize there is `by` keyword